# Google Chrome V61 loading forever when debug using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

I have updated Google chrome to version 61. After updating, when I tried to launch my application through visual studio 2017 Google Chrome loading forever. But I am able to launch using IE.

Any solution for this issue!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Some how I have managed to found an answer. Whenever I click the launch button, I have to give a hard-refresh in Google Chrome to open my website from visual studio.

But still wondering why we need to give hard-refresh.

Any suggestions much appreciated!!